# ¿Cómo promediar en una lista de enteros?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una página web con los estudiantes y sus notas y me gustaría agregar una línea que me dé su promedio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté lo siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
      <label>Text box</label>
      <input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
</p>

<p>
      <label>Tag box</label>
      <input type="Search for tags" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchTag()" placeholder="Search for tags..">
</p>

<ul id="txtOut"></ul>


</body>

<script>
fetch( 'https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students' )
  .then( function( response ) {
return response.json( );
  } )
  .then( function( myJson ) {
const divOut = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
var allStudents = myJson.students;
for( let k in allStudents ) {
  let txtOut = '';
  let listItem = document.createElement( 'li' );
  let grades =  `${allStudents[k].grades}`;
  let sum = values.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
  let avg = sum / values.length;

  // Añadimos el nombre como parte del dataset.
  listItem.dataset.nombre = allStudents[k].firstName.toUpperCase( );

  txtOut += `<b>${allStudents[k].firstName}</b><br />`;
  txtOut += `email: ${allStudents[k].email}<br />`;
  txtOut += `Company: ${allStudents[k].company}<br />`;
  txtOut += `Skill: ${allStudents[k].skill}<br />`;
  txtOut += `Average: ${avg}<br />`;
  txtOut += `Grades: ${allStudents[k].grades}<br />`;
  txtOut += `<img src="${allStudents[k].pic}"><hr />`;

  listItem.innerHTML = txtOut;
  divOut.appendChild( listItem );
}
  } );

function search() {
  const prefix = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ).value.toUpperCase( );
  const ul = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
  const childs = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
  var idx = -1, item;

  while( item = childs.item( ++idx ) ) {
//        console.log( typeof( item.dataset.nombre ), item.dataset.nombre );
item.style.display = item.dataset['nombre'].startsWith( prefix ) ? 'initial' : 
'none';
  }
}

function searchTag() {
  const prefix = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ).value.toUpperCase( );
  const ul = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
  const childs = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
  var idx = -1, item;

  while( item = childs.item( ++idx ) ) {
//        console.log( typeof( item.dataset.nombre ), item.dataset.nombre );
item.style.display = item.dataset['nombre'].startsWith( prefix ) ? 'initial' : 
'none';
  }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Pero me da un error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: Me parece tu error es aquí let grades =  ${allStudents[k].grades}; pues te faltan las backticks o comillas simples invertidas para encerrar esa declaración

Comment: @anonimo Gracias por el commentario. Quieres decir `let grades =  `${allStudents[k].grades}`;`?

Comment: Si trata y me dices

Comment: @anonimo Entonces traté `let grades =  '${allStudents[k].grades}';` con los ` pero obtengo `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: values is not defined`. Actualicé la pregunta para mostrarlo